# How can I grab the current timestamp and add minutes to it in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to add minutes to a timestamp in CakePHP. I want the timestamp to be grabbed when the form is processed.

Keep in mind, I'm just learning this stuff.

Here is my form code in my index view...

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Text');
$expirations = array('9999999'=>'Never','10'=>'10 Minutes','60'=>'1 Hour','1440'=>'1 Day','10080'=>'1 Week','40320'=>'1 Month','525600'=>'1 Year');
echo $this->Form->input('expiration', array('options' => $expirations), array('empty'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->end('Upload');
?>
```

I want to take the value from my 'expiration' input and add that amount of minutes to the current time.

The PHP code I currently use for this is:

```
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL $expiration MINUTE)
```

where $expiration is the number of minutes to add.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where did you get the idea that input has more parameters?

it is supposed to be (as documented):

```
 echo $this->Form->input('expiration', array('options' => $expirations, 'empty'=>false));
```

PS: a good IDE will tell you that via code completion that there is no such param.

As for your question: You can modify the data before saving in several ways:

a) in the controller level

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    $this->request['Text']['expiration'] += $yourValue; // we modify it first and then save it 
    if ($this->Text->save($this->request->data)) {...}
}
```

b) in the model as callback (recommended)

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['expiration'])) {
         $this->data[$this->alias]['expiration'] += $yourValue;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? there are a few php functions to return the current time.. time() for instance.

Comment: <? $yourValue = time(); ?> That will give you the time, and then you just use Mark's code above.

Answer (score 0):

Won't

```
$expiration += ($minutes * 60);
```

do the trick, or did I miss something?

Comment: where did you grab the current time?